# How can we control push button in VC6 gui by keyboard instead of mouse click?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

I have designed a GUI in VC6 win32 that has a menu bar and I want to control the menu bar using the keyboard arrows instead of mouse. My main function is called void CVCDlg. Is there any method or function or built-in function I can used to create a menu shortcut so for any menu option i assign a shourtcut for example i have an Open option and i want to create a shortcut for it as Ctrl+O.

Thanks

Comment: That I believe is what you call `accelerator keys`, and there are ways of creating them in Win32.  But why are you using such an old compiler, from 20 years ago?

Comment: That is what my university has asked me to do.

Comment: Hi I tried to use the accelerator keys then I added an accelerator table for each key on my menu. I then tried to load the accelerator table using this code  but it still does not work, any thoughts ?                            void CVCDlg::ACCELERATOR(  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  LPCSTR    lpTableName) 
{
HACCEL hAccel = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ACCELERATOR1));
}

Comment: I really think you should get concrete examples from good books (such as ones written by Charles Petzold) on Win32 programming.  Win32 API programming is hard enough, and you won't get too far trying to guess what should be done.